# Sum of indicator functions

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose

- $\{x_i,i\geq1\}$ - *i.i.d.* values
- ***u*** is some constant (f.e. $u = 0$)
- ***n*** is predetermined constant as well (f.e. $n = 100$)

How to calculate the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\{x_i\geq u\}}=\ldots~? $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired sum is simply a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $$p = \Pr[X \ge u],$$ where $X$ is the common random variable corresponding to the sample $\{x_i\}_{i \ge 1}$.